# How do I get the list of cipher suites supported in a specific TLS version?

Tags: tls, ciphers

Is there any cipher suites supported in one TLS version and not supported in the other? If yes, then is there any documentation that talks about the cipher suites supported in each TLS or SSL versions?

Comment: Is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cipher_suite#Supported_algorithms not enough?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, the documentation you are looking for are the RFC documents for the various versions.
Here are the links to the RFCs for TLS 1.0, 1.1, 1.2 and 1.3:

- [TLS 1.0](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/rfc2246/)
- [TLS 1.1](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/rfc4346/)
- [TLS 1.2](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/rfc5246/)
- [TLS 1.3](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/rfc8446/)

Since this would be a link-only answer, here the core of each RFC.

## TLS 1.0

The chapter *9. Mandatory Cipher Suits* reads the following:

> In the absence of an application profile standard specifying otherwise, a TLS compliant application MUST implement the cipher suite `TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA`.

This means that, unless and application profile says otherwise, a compliant application only has to implement `TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA` to be compliant to TLS 1.0. Of course, more ciphers were defined by TLS 1.0, and implementations were free to include even more, but to be TLS 1.0 compliant, this was the absolute minimum.

A complete list of all TLS 1.0 standardized ciphers is found in *Appendix C. CipherSuite definitions*:

```
CipherSuite                      Is       Key          Cipher      Hash
                             Exportable Exchange

TLS_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL               * NULL           NULL        NULL
TLS_RSA_WITH_NULL_MD5                 * RSA            NULL         MD5
TLS_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA                 * RSA            NULL         SHA
TLS_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5        * RSA_EXPORT     RC4_40       MD5
TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5                RSA            RC4_128      MD5
TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA                RSA            RC4_128      SHA
TLS_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_RC2_CBC_40_MD5    * RSA_EXPORT     RC2_CBC_40   MD5
TLS_RSA_WITH_IDEA_CBC_SHA               RSA            IDEA_CBC     SHA
TLS_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA     * RSA_EXPORT     DES40_CBC    SHA
TLS_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA                RSA            DES_CBC      SHA
TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA           RSA            3DES_EDE_CBC SHA
TLS_DH_DSS_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA  * DH_DSS_EXPORT  DES40_CBC    SHA
TLS_DH_DSS_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA             DH_DSS         DES_CBC      SHA
TLS_DH_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA        DH_DSS         3DES_EDE_CBC SHA
TLS_DH_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA  * DH_RSA_EXPORT  DES40_CBC    SHA
TLS_DH_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA             DH_RSA         DES_CBC      SHA
TLS_DH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA        DH_RSA         3DES_EDE_CBC SHA
TLS_DHE_DSS_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA * DHE_DSS_EXPORT DES40_CBC    SHA
TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA            DHE_DSS        DES_CBC      SHA
TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA       DHE_DSS        3DES_EDE_CBC SHA
TLS_DHE_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA * DHE_RSA_EXPORT DES40_CBC    SHA
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA            DHE_RSA        DES_CBC      SHA
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA       DHE_RSA        3DES_EDE_CBC SHA
TLS_DH_anon_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5    * DH_anon_EXPORT RC4_40       MD5
TLS_DH_anon_WITH_RC4_128_MD5            DH_anon        RC4_128      MD5
TLS_DH_anon_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA   DH_anon        DES40_CBC    SHA
TLS_DH_anon_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA            DH_anon        DES_CBC      SHA
TLS_DH_anon_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA       DH_anon        3DES_EDE_CBC SHA
```

## TLS 1.1

Similarly to TLS 1.0, TLS 1.1 defines in chapter *9. Mandatory Cipher Suits* the following:

> In the absence of an application profile standard specifying otherwise, a TLS compliant application MUST implement the cipher suite `TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA`.

Again, the complete list of all standardized ciphers is found again in *Appendix C. CipherSuite Definitions*:

```
CipherSuite                           Key Exchange   Cipher      Hash

TLS_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL               NULL           NULL        NULL
TLS_RSA_WITH_NULL_MD5                 RSA            NULL         MD5
TLS_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA                 RSA            NULL         SHA
TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5              RSA            RC4_128      MD5
TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA              RSA            RC4_128      SHA
TLS_RSA_WITH_IDEA_CBC_SHA             RSA            IDEA_CBC     SHA
TLS_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA              RSA            DES_CBC      SHA
TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA         RSA            3DES_EDE_CBC SHA
TLS_DH_DSS_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA           DH_DSS         DES_CBC      SHA
TLS_DH_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA      DH_DSS         3DES_EDE_CBC SHA
TLS_DH_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA           DH_RSA         DES_CBC      SHA
TLS_DH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA      DH_RSA         3DES_EDE_CBC SHA
TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA          DHE_DSS        DES_CBC      SHA
TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA     DHE_DSS        3DES_EDE_CBC SHA
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA          DHE_RSA        DES_CBC      SHA
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA     DHE_RSA        3DES_EDE_CBC SHA
TLS_DH_anon_WITH_RC4_128_MD5          DH_anon        RC4_128      MD5
TLS_DH_anon_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA          DH_anon        DES_CBC      SHA
TLS_DH_anon_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA     DH_anon        3DES_EDE_CBC SHA
```

## TLS 1.2

Chapter *9. Mandatory Cipher Suits* again tells us the minimum required supported ciphersuites for TLS 1.2:

> In the absence of an application profile standard specifying otherwise, a TLS-compliant application MUST implement the cipher suite `TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA` (see Appendix A.5 for the definition).

The complete list can be found again in *Appendix C. CipherSuite Definitions*:

```
Cipher Suite                            Key        Cipher         Mac
                                        Exchange

TLS_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL                 NULL         NULL         NULL
TLS_RSA_WITH_NULL_MD5                   RSA          NULL         MD5
TLS_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA                   RSA          NULL         SHA
TLS_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA256                RSA          NULL         SHA256
TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5                RSA          RC4_128      MD5
TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA                RSA          RC4_128      SHA
TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA           RSA          3DES_EDE_CBC SHA
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA            RSA          AES_128_CBC  SHA
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA            RSA          AES_256_CBC  SHA
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256         RSA          AES_128_CBC  SHA256
TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256         RSA          AES_256_CBC  SHA256
TLS_DH_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA        DH_DSS       3DES_EDE_CBC SHA
TLS_DH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA        DH_RSA       3DES_EDE_CBC SHA
TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA       DHE_DSS      3DES_EDE_CBC SHA
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA       DHE_RSA      3DES_EDE_CBC SHA
TLS_DH_anon_WITH_RC4_128_MD5            DH_anon      RC4_128      MD5
TLS_DH_anon_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA       DH_anon      3DES_EDE_CBC SHA
TLS_DH_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA         DH_DSS       AES_128_CBC  SHA
TLS_DH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA         DH_RSA       AES_128_CBC  SHA
TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA        DHE_DSS      AES_128_CBC  SHA
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA        DHE_RSA      AES_128_CBC  SHA
TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA        DH_anon      AES_128_CBC  SHA
TLS_DH_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA         DH_DSS       AES_256_CBC  SHA
TLS_DH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA         DH_RSA       AES_256_CBC  SHA
TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA        DHE_DSS      AES_256_CBC  SHA
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA        DHE_RSA      AES_256_CBC  SHA
TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA        DH_anon      AES_256_CBC  SHA
TLS_DH_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256      DH_DSS       AES_128_CBC  SHA256
TLS_DH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256      DH_RSA       AES_128_CBC  SHA256
TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256     DHE_DSS      AES_128_CBC  SHA256
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256     DHE_RSA      AES_128_CBC  SHA256
TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256     DH_anon      AES_128_CBC  SHA256
TLS_DH_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256      DH_DSS       AES_256_CBC  SHA256
TLS_DH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256      DH_RSA       AES_256_CBC  SHA256
TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256     DHE_DSS      AES_256_CBC  SHA256
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256     DHE_RSA      AES_256_CBC  SHA256
TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256     DH_anon      AES_256_CBC  SHA256
```

## TLS 1.3

TLS 1.3 is a bit more demanding with minimum requirements. Chapter *9. Compliance Requirements* again states what an application needs to implement at minimum to be compliant to TLS 1.3, but it's more than a single cipher suite.

> In the absence of an application profile standard specifying otherwise:
>
> - A TLS-compliant application MUST implement the `TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256` cipher suite and SHOULD implement the`TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384` and `TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256` cipher suites (see Appendix B.4).
> - A TLS-compliant application MUST support digital signatures with `rsa_pkcs1_sha256` (for certificates), `rsa_pss_rsae_sha256` (for CertificateVerify and certificates), and `ecdsa_secp256r1_sha256`.  A TLS-compliant application MUST support key exchange with `secp256r1` (NIST P-256) and SHOULD support key exchange with `X25519`.

Furthermore, chapter *9.2. Mandatory-to-Implement Extensions* lists many mandatory extensions that a TLS 1.3 compliant application must implement. These are too many to list here, but the RFC is linked at the top of the question if you want to see those yourself.

Finally, the *Appendix B.4 Cipher Suites* defines the following Cipher Suites:

```
+------------------------------+-------------+
| Description                  | Value       |
+------------------------------+-------------+
| TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256       | {0x13,0x01} |
|                              |             |
| TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384       | {0x13,0x02} |
|                              |             |
| TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256 | {0x13,0x03} |
|                              |             |
| TLS_AES_128_CCM_SHA256       | {0x13,0x04} |
|                              |             |
| TLS_AES_128_CCM_8_SHA256     | {0x13,0x05} |
+------------------------------+-------------+
```

As you can see, this list has been reduced quite a lot. Turns out supporting a ton of cipher suites with questionable security is not a great idea.

Comment: There are lots of ciphersuites defined for TLS1.0-1.2 by RFCs other than the base RFCs; see 3268 4132 5932 6367 4279 4785 5487 5489 4492 8422 5054 4162 5288 5289 6655 7251 7905 6209 and maybe more I've missed. OTOH RC4 is in all 3 base RFCs but removed by 7465, AFAIK there are no additions or changes to 1.3 suites yet, but there probably will be, especially if anyone important standardizes post-quantum.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Feel free to add them. I felt that the question was about base TLS, and if taken literally, then the answer would just be the absolute minimum cipher.